# Open Graph Object Debugger Bad Response Code http 400

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

the Open Graph Object Debugger shows an error with a url for existing scrape information, after fetching new information its fixed, but every time the crawler scrapes the website again, the error appears again.

for example this url: [https://www.webteb.com/multimedia/videos/علاج-جفاف-الفم](https://www.webteb.com/multimedia/videos/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%AC%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%85)

i've checked our server logs (iis) there are no http 400 for this url in the same day that the debugger shows the error happened.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple times and the URL is being scraped correctly. The unencoded form of the url seems to be the issue. Pop in the encoded version `https://www.webteb.com/multimedia/videos/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%AC%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%85` into the debugger and fetch new scrape informaiton; it should work fine.

Comment: thats the problem, when checking the cached version it has errors, but fetching new scrape information always fixes it until some time later its corrupted.
note that in the og:url the url is encoded.

Comment: checked again with 'Show existing scrape information' and seems to work fine. Used the encoded url in the debugger: https://www.webteb.com/multimedia/videos/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%AC%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%85